# Simple ngTable with large JSON not showing any data in cells

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-4, ngtable

I have a large json file almost 5 MB in size with the following array format.
There are about 3000 records.

I am using microsoft mvc 4 and angular + ngTable to display this data in the front end. It needs to be searchable and sortable on all columns.
The server side code does not take any arguments and returns all 3000 records in the format below.

```
  {
"MR": "Inact",
"EncType": null,
"ClientAlias": 111020.0,
"OrgName": "Zic",
"CharacterAlias": null,
"Account#": 30645147.0,
"MRN": null,
"PlanCode": null,
"Address": "PO Box 123456",
"City": "Richmond ",
"St": "VA",
"ZIP": 23298.0,
"ContactName": "Jonny J",
"Fax": "(111) 111-1111",
"PHONE": "pager 111-1111",
"CriticalValueNotification": null,
"ClientPracticeTesting": null,
"Doctor": "John Smith",
"BeginDate": 36395.0,
"medBeginDate": null
  }
```

The javascript file (app.js) contains the following code.
I have a separate files for the views as shown in the angular code below.

For ease of understanding the question, I have put everything in one snippet below.

```
 var flexTable = angular.module("flexTable", ["ngRoute", "ngTable", "ngResource"]);

flexTable.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: '../../about.html',
        controller: 'tableController'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: '../../contact.html',
        controller: 'tableController'
    })
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../../table.html',
        controller: 'tableController'
    })
    .when('/table', {
        templateUrl: '../../table.html',
        controller: 'tableController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/table'
    });


}]);

flexTable.controller('tableController',['$scope', '$resource' ,'ngTableParams', function ($scope, $resource,ngTableParams) {
    var data = '';
    var api = $resource("/Home/GetData")
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({}, {
    getData: function (params) {



        var varApiGet = api.get(params.url()).$promise.then(function (data) {
            params.total(data.inlineCount);
            return data.results;
        });
        return varApiGet;
    }
});
}]);
```

The html page looks as follows

```
  <%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
  <head runat="server">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="../../Assets/css/justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link href="../../Assets/css/ng-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
          <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-resource.js"></script>
          <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-route.js"></script>
          <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
          <script src="../../Assets/js/lib/ng-table.min.js"></script>
          <script src="../../Assets/js/app.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container" >
          <!-- The justified navigation menu is meant for single line per list item.
             Multiple lines will require custom code not provided by Bootstrap. -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#navbar">Default</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>

          <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Instructions stuff!</h1>
        <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. 
            Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, 
            ut fermentum massa justo sit amet.</p>
        <!--<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Get started today</a></p>-->
    </div>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="tableController">
        <div ng-view>
<div class="row">


    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data track by $index">
            <td title="'EncType'">
                {{row.EncType}}
            </td>
            <td title="'ClientAlias'">
                {{row.ClientAlias}}
            </td>
            <td title="'OrgName'">
                {{row.OrgName}}
            </td>
            <td title="'CharacterAlias'">
                {{row.CharacterAlias}}
            </td>
            <td title="'AddressCity'">
                {{row.AddressCity}}
            </td>
            <td title="'St'">
                {{row.St}}
            </td>
            <td title="'ZIP'">
                {{row.ZIP}}
            </td>
            <td title="'ContactName'">
                {{row.ContactName}}
            </td>
            <td title="'Fax'">
                {{row.Fax}}
            </td>
            <td title="'PHONE'">
                {{row.PHONE}}
            </td>
            <td title="'CriticalValueNotification'">
                {{row.CriticalValueNotification}}
            </td>
            <td title="'Doctor'">
                {{row.Doctor}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
      <footer class="footer">
          <p>&copy; 2015 Company, Inc.</p>
      </footer>

      </div><!--container-->
  </body>
  </html>
```

When I have the data hardcoded in the javascript controller function, the table displays fine without the search and sort functionality. When I have the data come in through the ajax call as shown in the code, it displays no data. only the table heading.

I can answer any questions that anyone has about this.

Thanks,
Paras

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the controller code that worked for me. I also added some extra code for the sorting and the filters.

```
flexTable.controller('tableController', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngTableParams', '$filter', '$log'
   , function ($scope, $http, ngTableParams, $filter, $log) { //


   $http.get('/Home/GetData')
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10,          // count per page
                sorting: {
                    OrganizationName: 'asc'     // initial sorting
                }
            }
                , {
                    total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
                    getData: function ($defer, params) {
                        // use build-in angular filter
                        var filterData = params.filter() ?
                                            $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) :
                                            $scope.data;
                        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                            $filter('orderBy')(filterData, params.orderBy()) :
                                            filterData;

                        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    }
                }
             );


        });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `$http` instead of `$resource`. Your response data will be in the `data` property of your response. Try the following:

```
 $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({}, {
   getData: function(params) {
     var varApiGet = $http.get(params.url()).then(function(response) {
       var data = response.data;
       params.total(data.inlineCount);
       return data.results;
     });
     return varApiGet;
   }
 });
```

**Edit**

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/ww74n2at/) is a working fiddle. I simulated the response as an array with one entry (the one you posted in the question). Make sure that your response data is in the correct format.

Comment: I get the following error now.                                                       TypeError: Cannot read property 'inlineCount' of undefined
        at app.js:49
        at angular.js:15757
        at m.$eval (angular.js:17025)
        at m.$digest (angular.js:16841)
        at m.$apply (angular.js:17133)
        at g (angular.js:11454)
        at x (angular.js:11652)
        at XMLHttpRequest.v.onload (angular.js:11593)

Comment: oh sorry, when I tried your code I used  $http instead of $resource, and the result is not the same. Could you do post your `console.log(reposnse)` or in your code `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: console.log(data) gives a huge object with the following {0: "[", 1: "
", 2: "↵", 3: " ", 4: " ", 5: "{", 6: "
", 7: "↵", 8: " ", 9: " ", 10: " ", 11: " ", 12: """, 13: "M", 14: "R", 15: """, 16: ":", 17: " ", 18: """, 19: "P", 20: "T", 21: """, 22: ",", 23: "......

Comment: Seems like that is the data separated by each letter in the object.

Comment: I don't think `$resource` is fitted in your case. It is used to manage REST resources like an 'Article', 'User' etc. and not arrays of data. Do you specifically need to use `$resource` ? If not you should use `$http` or alternatives.

Comment: I do not need to use `$resource` in particular. I did use `$http` but somehow the tables appeared, but with no text in the rows. Does that happen frequently?

Comment: Normally, if your response data is as expected, your binding should work properly. I updated the answer with an example fiddle. Could you check and eventually update your question with a sample exact response data ?

Comment: Hi, The fiddle that you gave me worked for me. I also did come up with a slightly different solution. I will edit the question and post the code.